# Trouble Generating .exe File Using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to package my python script so that I can share it with users who do not have python installed. I use

```
pyinstaller --onefile matcher.py
```

to generate the .exe file as expected. However, when I attempt to run that .exe file I am presented with the following prompt, which shows quickly before closing itself.

[image: Errors Generated]

I am at a loss for what I need to do in order for the packaged python script to run correctly. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: are you using a virtual enviroment?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a conda environment setup specifically for this python script.

Comment: Please see this: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2978